# How do I change a keyboard key function?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping

I do not use my right <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and I would like to have a <kbd>Underline</kbd> key on that place.

Is there a way to configure my right <kbd>Alt</kbd> to be an underline character key?

update: using Windows 7

Comment: By "underline key" you mean something like Ctrl+U in Word, or did you mean the underscore key? If the former, there's no generic key for that and different apps may use different shortcuts, so this will probably require a fairly complex AutoHotkey script that will do per-app key remapping.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com). You can use that program to assign different functions to your keys or you can create your own keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator. With that you can create you own keyboard layout and install it on you computer in control panel -> keyboard. You should be able to map Alt to what ever you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx